# Knockout Mapping Response to Object

Tags: knockout.js

I have a user object like so:

```
var userModel = {
    Id: ko.observable(),
    Email: ko.observable().extend({ email: true, required: true, maxLength: 200 }),
    FirstName: ko.observable().extend({ required: true, minLength: 2, maxLength: 200 }),
    LastName: ko.observable().extend({ required:true, minLength: 2, maxLength: 200 }),
    DefaultLanguage: ko.observable(),
    Phone: ko.observable().extend({phoneUS:true}),
    AvatarUrl: ko.observable(),
    Claims: ko.observableArray()
};
```

I am loading a response and want to bind the response to the object. The response is in the exactly same format as the model:

```
self.user = userModel;
self.loadData = function (params) {
        $.get('/api/user/' + params.id).then(function (data) {
            console.log('GET User', data);
            self.user.Id(data.Id);
            self.user.Email(data.Email);
            self.user.FirstName(data.FirstName);
            self.user.LastName(data.LastName);
            self.user.Phone(data.Phone);
            self.user.DefaultLanguage(data.DefaultLanguage);
            self.user.AvatarUrl(data.AvatarUrl);
            self.user.Claims(data.Claims);
        });
    };
```

While the above works great its really long. Is there a shorter way to bind the object?

Comment: You can use 'ko.mapping.fromJS() '  (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Comment: Tried that it doesn't work as self.user is not a function.

Comment: This don't work?  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.user);

Comment: Jose that does work. I didn't try it like that thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript reflection

```
$.get('/api/user/' + params.id).then(function (data) {
            for(var i in data){
                if(data.hasOwnProperty(i) && self.user.hasOwnProperty(i))
                {
                      self.user[i](data[i]);
                }
            }
        });
```

This can be moved into a function and make things a lot easier.  It does become more complicated when you have a nested structure of observable objects and combination of observable and standard properties.  But based on your example this will work.

Also.  ko.mapping.fromJS will work, but can be a pain sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern I like to use is a hydrate/re-hydrate. [Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/tyrsius/pen/qbKaGL?editors=1010) demonstrating this.

```
var User = function(init) {
  var self = this;
  self.firstName = ko.observable();
  self.lastName = ko.observable();
  self.city = ko.observable();

  this.update = function(data) {
    data = data || {};
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
      self[key](data[key]);
    });
  }
  this.update(init);
}
```

This allows updates to be made easily by anyone, for as many properties as necessary.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  user.update({
    firstName: 'Tim',
    lastName: 'Moran',
    city: 'Portland'
  })
}, 2000)
```

However, this can get tedious if done on a lot of models, so you can pull it into a base model.

```
var baseViewModel = {
  update: function(data) {
    data = data || {};
    var self = this;
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
      self[key](data[key]);
    });
  }
}

var User = function(init) {
  var self = this;
  self.firstName = ko.observable();
  self.lastName = ko.observable();
  self.city = ko.observable();

  this.update(init);
};

User.prototype = baseViewModel;
```